# onActivityResult always got -1 as resultcode

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I try to use `MediaProjectionManager` to capture a screenshot. The first step I take is typing following lines of code:

```
MediaProjectionManager projectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
startActivityForResult(projectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), 1);
```

Then I expect to get responded with the `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` function. However I find that the `resultCode` is always -1 and the data always contains null uri and null mData. Its like there is no image content passed to `onActivityResult`.

Does anyone know what caused this issue or how to retrieve the screenshot from the data?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take a look to the Activity.RESULT_OK.

```
public static final int RESULT_OK = -1;
```

So if you get a -1 in your resultCode you're good.

Next after reading the [MediaProjectionManager documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager.html#createScreenCaptureIntent())

I read that you need to call getMediaProjection.
Try to call getMediaProjection method in your onActivityResult and give it the resultCode and resultData.

To get a basic sample, look this code => [MediaProjectionManager use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812590/android-mediaprojection-recover-black-image)

Hope it can help you !!

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer works well and save me so much time. I successfully captured a screenshot with your sample code.

Comment: Cool  . If you think it s the right answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

requestcode is always -1 if it give some output you have to check resultcode 
and is 1.like this

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                    //do your stuff
                break;


        }
    }
}
```